# AWS Route53 records update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, dns, amazon-route53

I am new to Route53 service of AWS.

I have to setup/modify Route53 dns entries, the following is requested by external service provider to setup in AWS Route53:

```
Type            Name          Value          TTL
A               @             <ipaddress>    3600
CNAME           www           <domain>.com   3600
```

This dns record update is confusing me.

For the first entry above (Type A) - what Record name I should create in Route53?

If I look at second entry above (Type CNAME) - it seems it's telling me to create www..com record in route 53?

What record entries do I have to make/update in Route53 hosted zone?

Following is the existing configuration I have in my Route53 AWS account:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this [cheat sheet](https://constellix.com/news/dns-record-types-cheat-sheet) first.

Each type has its own usage. As first glance, you should create record A point to your application, and CNAME to redirect from www to.